# How to create a service on linux Centos 6

Tags: linux, bash, service, centos, centos6.5

How to create service on centos 6 to kill service and run script

For example :

If i run this command  service test start

it should make the below

```
pkill test
nohup ./opt/test/test/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml
```

Also if i run this command  service test stop

it should make the below

```
pkill test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file like /etc/init.d/test

```
#!/bin/bash

start() {
    /usr/bin/kill -9 $(cat /tmp/test_nohup_pid.txt)
    nohup ./opt/test/test/bin/standalone.sh -c standalone-full.xml 2>&1 &
    echo $! > /tmp/test_nohup_pid.txt
}

stop() {
    /usr/bin/kill -9 $(cat /tmp/test_nohup_pid.txt)
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

case "$1" in
  start)
        start
        ;;
  stop)
        stop
        ;;
  restart)
        restart
        ;;
  *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
        exit 1
esac
```